# How to get only parameters part from an url in struts2 use <s:url> tag?

Tags: url, struts2, jsp-tags

For example, I have an URL: /test.action?a=1&b=2
Now I want in jsp page use  to get only "a=1&b=2" out of the URL, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Action Code

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String a;
     private String a;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // do something here
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(final String a) {
        this.a= a;
    }

 public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(final String b) {
        this.a= a;
    }
}
```

Using Struts tags:

```
<s:property value="a"/>
<s:property value="b"/>
```

Still i am not sure what exactly is your requirement as its not very clear from your question

```
Just a side note <s:url> This tag is used to create a URL
```

Comment: I want to create an url as a property to set a field, but I just need the parameters part in <s:url>. So here I just want to know is that possible only use struts tag to extract those parameters.

Comment: you can set them in some hidden text fields and can use them where ever you want

Comment: I agree with umesh to use <s:property> if you require them on the page, else use hidden variables to transport them wherever you want.